# What does means <Props> in 'export default class App extends Component<Props>' when i create a project using react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am familiar with react and now i have just created a react native project using react-native init command. I noticed in App.js file like this ,

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

}
```

What does mean `<Props>` here.?

Comment: Are you sure you're on App.js and not App.tsx?

Comment: yes it is App.js file in root directory. I also noticed that `type Props = {};` just above this line

Comment: That's typescript syntax. It's where you define the type of values that gets passed down to your App component.

Edit: Refer to Kraylog's answer. I forgot about flow.

Comment: @Javascriptonian thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code uses Flow, which is a type checker for JavaScript written by Facebook.

The React documentation explains how it is used [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/):

> We removed our dependency on prop-types and added a Flow object type named Props with the same shape as the prop types but using Flow’s static type syntax. Then we passed our new Props type into React.Component as a type argument.

The Flow type checker can then tell you if you're sending wrong types as your component props (instead of using `prop-types`).

Answer (score 1):

That's for `Flow` type. You can read about `react-native`'s flow types here https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809